# si la variable es menor que barco, generar otro numero aleatorio - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este ejercicio es una simulacion de un sistema de llegada de barcos jugando con numeros aleatorios. 
Inicialmente se corre un número aleatorio para saber cuantos barcos llegan en el dia. inmediatamente se genera otro para ver cuantos barcos de los que llegaron pueden descargar mercancia. Los que no pudieron descargar ese dia, lo podran hacer al siguiente, y se acumulará a los barcos del siguiente dia.
un ejemplo de lo que seria el programa:

```
#   ALEAT   BARCOS  ACUM    ALEAT2  DESCARGADOS RESTANTE
1   0.678     3       0     0.823       2          1
2   0.806     4       1     0.401       3          2
3   0.967     5       2     0.785       5          2
4   0.116     1       2     0.463       2          1
5   0.760     4       1     0.850       4          1
6   0.103     0       1     0.019       0          1
7   0.849     4       1     0.524       2          3
8   0.566     3       3     0.215       3          3
9   0.567     4       3     0.936       4          3
10  0.122     5       3     0.398       4          4
11  0.455     1       4     0.533       1          4
12  0.165     1       4     0.883       1          4
13  0.031     2       4     0.983       2          4
14  0.571     5       4     0.357       3          6
15  0.513     1       6     0.835       1          6
```

En el codigo que tengo, genero un # aleatorio para saber cuando barcos entran a descargar, la variable descargados no debe ser mayor al número de barcos que llegan. mi idea fue hacer un `while` para generar otro # aleatorio hasta que se 
 generara una cantidad menor a barcos que llegan.
Ahora me saca error cuando corro el programa, otras veces se congela las simulaciones y no termina, como si el programa no pudiera generar el aleatorio para el el numero de descargos dea menor que el # de barcos, y tengo que parar el programa.

Acum -> almacena los barcos que quedaron sin descargar = variable restante.
barcos -> el total de barco que llegaron al dia.
descargados -> los barcos que descargaron en el dia.

pongo mi codigo para que lo observen.

```
from random import random

class barco():
    def dia_descargo(self):
        if aleat2 <0.05:
            self.descargados = 1
        elif aleat2 < 0.2:
            self.descargados = 2  
        elif aleat2 < 0.7:
            self.descargados = 3       
        elif aleat2 < 0.9:
            self.descargados = 4        
        else:
            self.descargados = 5
        return self.descargados

barco=barco()
i=1
Acum = 0
count = 0

print("#\tALEAT\tBARCOS\tACUM\tALEAT\tBdESCAR\tREST")
while i <= 15:
    aleat=random()
    if aleat < 0.13:
        barcos = 0
    elif aleat < 0.3:
        barcos = 1
    elif aleat < 0.45:
        barcos = 2
    elif aleat < 0.7:
        barcos = 3
    elif aleat < 0.9:
        barco = 4
    else:
        barcos = 5

    while True:
        aleat2 = random()
        barco.dia_descargo()
        if barcos < barco.descargados:
            aleat2 = random()
            barco.dia_descargo()
        else:
            break


    restan = barcos - barco.descargados


    count += restan
    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(i,str(aleat)[0:5],barcos,Acum,str(aleat2)[0:5],barco.descargados,restan))

    Acum = restan
    i+=1

print("el total de barcos con retardo son: {}".format(count))
```

la salida del programa es:

```
#       ALEAT   BARCOS  ACUM    ALEAT   BdESCAR REST
1       0.569   3       0       0.041   1       2
2       0.265   1       2       0.020   1       0
3       0.527   3       0       0.276   3       0
4       0.993   5       0       0.988   5       0
5       0.972   5       0       0.522   3       2
6       0.276   1       2       0.039   1       0
7       0.372   2       0       0.101   2       0
8       0.555   3       0       0.466   3       0
9       0.223   1       0       0.049   1       0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cisco\Documents\barcos.py", line 38, in <module>
    barco.dia_descargo()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dia_descargo'
```

¿Que esta ocacionado el error? ¿Cómo se puede resolver el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que el compilador detecta que la variable `barco` es de tipo entera e intentas acceder a un método que no existe para ese tipo de dato, y esto lo ocasiona por un error de escritura aquí en donde realicé el comentario:

```
barco=barco()
i=1
Acum = 0
count = 0

print("#\tALEAT\tBARCOS\tACUM\tALEAT\tBdESCAR\tREST")
while i <= 15:
    aleat=random()
    if aleat < 0.13:
        barcos = 0
    elif aleat < 0.3:
        barcos = 1
    elif aleat < 0.45:
        barcos = 2
    elif aleat < 0.7:
        barcos = 3
    elif aleat < 0.9:
        #Aqui esta tu error, debería ser barcos = 4
        barco = 4
    else:
        barcos = 5
```

Ya que con esto estas cambiando el objeto que habías creado llamado `barco` por un número entero.

Comment: Efectivamente, era  ´barcos´ en lugar de ´barco´.  Muchas Gracias